# Sending a list of different objects via SignalR

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

What is the best way to send a list of different objects via SignalR to the clients?

When i use a list of objects with the same base, the client only receive properties of the base class:

```
class Update { }
class UpdateA { public string PropertyA {get; set;}}
class UpdateB { public string PropertyB {get; set;}}
...
IEnumerable<Update> updates = GetUpdates();
await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("update", updates);
```

When I use pre serialized data in form of strings, the serialzier escapte the json data as strings.

```
IEnumerable<string> updates = GetUpdates();
await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("update", updates);
// data looks like: [ "{...}", "{...}" ]
```

Do I have to write my own serialzier? How does it work for SignalR in dotnet core?

Comment: Why not directly use a complex class and inlcude all the objects , and at last send to clients?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but here is an other solution that does not requires to write your own `CustomConverter` and relies on the `NewtonSoft` solution instead:

1. First you need to install this package:  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.NewtonsoftJson`
2. On the server side, you need to add the following calls in you `Startup.cs` class:

   ```
   services.AddSignalR()
       .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol(opts => 
           opts.PayloadSerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto);
   ```
3. if your client is a C# client, you have to add the same configuration when building the connection:

   ```
   new HubConnectionBuilder()
       .WithUrl("/yourhub")
       .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol(opts => 
           opts.PayloadSerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)
       .Build();
   ```

If your client is not a C# client, I guess you will have to manage the deserialization yourself. `NewtonSoft.Json` just adds a `$type` property to the generated JSON containing the fully qualified type name (for example: `Your.Namespace.ClassName`) so you can use it to select the according type to deserialize with.

source: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-newtonsoftjson-in-an-aspnet-core-30-no-locsignalr-project)

Answer (score 2):

> send a list of different objects with the same base via SignalR to the clients

You can try to achieve the requirement by creating and using a custom converter, like below.

*In custom converter `MyConverterWithTypeDiscriminator`*

```
public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Update value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    writer.WriteStartObject();

    if (value is UpdateA updateA)
    {
        writer.WriteNumber("TypeDiscriminator", (int)TypeDiscriminator.UpdateA);
        writer.WriteString("PropertyA", updateA.PropertyA);
    }
    else if (value is UpdateB updateB)
    {
        writer.WriteNumber("TypeDiscriminator", (int)TypeDiscriminator.UpdateB);
        writer.WriteString("PropertyB", updateB.PropertyB);
    }

    writer.WriteString("UpdatedAt", value.UpdatedAt);

    writer.WriteEndObject();
}
```

*Base class and derived classes*

```
public class Update
{
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateA : Update
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateB : Update
{
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

*In Startup.cs*

```
services.AddSignalR().AddJsonProtocol(options => options.PayloadSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new MyConverterWithTypeDiscriminator()));
```

*In Hub method*

```
var updates = new List<Update>
{
    new UpdateA
    {
        UpdatedAt=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
        PropertyA = "A"
    },
    new UpdateB
    {
        UpdatedAt=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
        PropertyB = "B"
    }
};

await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveUpdate", updates);
```

*Test Result*

[image]

Note: to implement your custom converter, please check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#support-polymorphic-deserialization